# Fetch file from particular date

Tags: unix, awk, grep, unix-timestamp, ls

New to Unix and I'm trying to fetch files from a directory having current date.
Tried below command, but it fetches some other file instead

```
cd /path/; ls -lrt abc833* | grep `date '+%d'`
```

Also I want to try something like below but it doesn't work

```
for file in /path/abc833*

if [ `$file | awk '{print $7}'` =`date '+%d'`];then

echo $file

fi
done
```

What's the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use find?

```
find ./ -ctime 1
```

returns all files created in last 24 hours. You also forgot to wrap date:

```
cd /path/; ls -lrt abc833* | grep $(date '+%d')
```

%d only gives number of day in month today would be "28". that would also match "20:28" or 28th of last month.

EDIT:

Syntax errors were in your first post. You wrapped the date command correctly.
Your second approach is full of syntax errors. And you are trying to execute each file to pass its output to awk => You forgot a `ls -l`

But same thought error for date there. `stat -c %Y <file>` gives you the modification time of a file in seconds since epoch, which is maybe easier to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/; ls -lrt abc833* | sed 1d | tr -s ' '|cut -d' ' -f9|grep $(date '+%d')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But how do I get the files along with their date?

Comment: cd /path/; ls -lrt abc833* | sed 1d | tr -s ' '|cut -d' ' -f7,8,9|grep $(date '+%d'). Do you want the file names having current date or files of current date?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the logic in `awk`:

```
ls -ltr | awk '{date=strftime("%d"); if($7==date){f="";for(i=9;i<=NF;i++){f=f" "$i} print f}}'
```

If your file name does not contain spaces it can be simplified:

```
ls -ltr | awk '{date=strftime("%d"); if($7==date){print $9}}'
```

And if instead of the file name you want the whole line from `ls -ltr`

```
ls -ltr | awk '{date=strftime("%d"); if($7==date){print $0}}'
```